# What is the priority of the modulo operator?

Tags: python

What is the priority of the modulo operator `%` in Python?

Example like this:

```
100 - 25 * 3 % 4
```

Comment: 1. Why not try it and see? 2. Why not [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)?

Comment: What jonrsharpe said. `25 * 3 % 4` evaluates like `(25 * 3) % 4`. But I recommend using parentheses to make it obvious.

Comment: Never use operators without parentheses, for example always write `2 + (3 * 4)` instead of `2 + 3 * 4`, even if the result is the same. Also in if statements, always write `if ((a == 1) and (b > 2)):` instead of `if a == 1 and b > 2:`.

Comment: @uri Yes, let's just ruin the entire point of having order of operations or precedence of operators!

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) document link, the priority is the same as division/multiplication. Thus, your expression will be

```
100 - ((25 * 3) % 4)
```